# machine-trasnlation tag?

Tags: discussion

The tag [machine-translation](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/machine-translation) is misspelled as [machine-trasnlation](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/machine-trasnlation). Although it is a pretty minor thing, it looks ugly and unprofessional, and hence I thought of bringing it to notice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there's only one question using this tag and it has no tag wiki entry, all that needs to be done to correct this problem is to edit the question and fix the spelling of the tag. Although both tags will still be visible in the system, [the empty tag will eventually be deleted automatically](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/112519/254929).

If there were more questions using the misspelled tag, it would simply take a bit longer to retag and [burninate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120640/254929).

On busier network sites, or when there are a lot of questions to go through, it's generally seen as best to leave burnination to users with bona fide edit privileges rather than suggesting a bunch of minor edits that would require community review. In our case, we only have a very small number of users who can manage that queue; but since there were other things worth improving about the question, it's worth a suggested edit (and I took care of the tag at the same time).